# perl regex fails for no apparent reason

Tags: regex, perl, rename

I'm trying to rename some tickets with the rename package, but I'm only getting return code 4 and no other output or errors.

I have already entered some articles, and I am not finding the problem in my expression.

The text pattern is:

```
companyName-mm.yyyy.pdf
```

And I would like the pattern

```
companyName-yyyy.mm.pdf
```

PS: the companyName has 5 letters

I tried these commands without success:

```bash
rename 's/(\w{5})-(\d{2}).(\d{4}).*/' 's/$1-$3\.$2\.pdf/' *.pdf
rename 's/(\w{5})-(\d{2}).(\d{4}).*/$1-$3\.$2\.pdf/' *.pdf
```

Nothing was renamed and all I got is return code 4.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

*Edited by @zdim: I lightly edited with clarifications given in a comment by OP*

Comment: The first command is broken, you have two single quoted commands with half a substitution in either half. The second command works as expected. Although you put the escaped periods `\.` in the wrong part of the substitution: In the first it would mean a literal period instead of a wildcard.

Comment: What exactly does "_without success_" mean?  Showing/stating errors helps people help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
rename -n s'/\w+-\K([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})(?=\.pdf)/$2.$1/' *pdf
```

Explanation

- `\w+` matches all consecutive "word-characters," `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So it stops matching at `-`, as needed.  If you want to restrict to five chars change to `\w{5}`.
- `\K` following the word-and-hyphen makes it drop all matches up to that point so they don't need to be captured and restored in the replacement part.
- Then the two-digit and four-digit numbers are captured, swapped in the replacement part.
- `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which asserts (only "looks" without consuming) that what follows the matched numbers is `.pdf`. A pedestrian way is to capture and put it back

  ```
  rename -n s'/\w+-\K([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})\.(pdf)/$2.$1.$3/' *pdf
  ```

  Here I don't capture `.` before `pdf` but type it back in as I find this clearer to look at.

Remove `-n` to actually rename once you inspect the printed output.

Note, the command comes in different names across systems (`prename` on CentOS etc).

See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for Perl's own regex tutorial.

---

The first command in the question is simply broken, as `s/.../` isn't a valid substitution operator. The second one works for me but that `.*` is potentially dangerous: it matches anything after the two numbers -- and regardless of what it is it replaces it with `.pdf`!

Comment: I followed all the suggestions answered and tried several ways, but I only got return code 4, and nothing was renamed.

I wish I could have used the program, but this time it was manual. I will certainly have other opportunities to find my mistake.

Comment: @RuanFaustinoCamelloDaSilva Hang on, we'll figure it out ... how do you get "_return code 4_", what does that mean?  (I don't see any returns documented for the command. Do you mean that it prints `4` to the terminal?)  What system (OS) do you run this on? (I am testing on CentOS.)

Comment: Let's try the most basic debugging -- try: `rename -n s'/(.*)/$1_XXX/' *pdf`.  This should only list what it would do (`-n`, but first check: make up some silly files and test on them), and we are telling it to replace the name with `name_XXX`

Comment: I can't get a `4` return (If you mean the shell's return, what's in `$?`) ... only `0`, `1`, or `2`.  The `4` in general could mean "_Interrupted system call_" (what could mean that the command is broken? but this is guessing).   Did this (`rename` on your system) ever work? Can you get it to work on any files, doing anything at all (the simplest thing, like the one I suggested above)?

Comment: code 4 means *"nothing was renamed"*, even when I don't use the -n argument.

It doesn't give the detailed error.

Comment: @RuanFaustinoCamelloDaSilva Ah, I see.  How about debugging I suggested in a comment above -- can you get it to do *anything*?  The command could be just broken on your system ? Or Perl could be?  Does Perl run normally?

Answer (score 0):

### Hey Ruan!

with the details you specified, I think this regex could solve your problem:

```
rename 's/(?<=\w{5}-)(\d{2}).(\d{4})/$2.$1/' *.pdf
```

It basically uses [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to not include the companyName result in a capture group but still validating if it matches or not with the alphabet characters and the length we specified.

It also does not read the ".pdf", so only 3 things are captured on the first section of the regex.

- 0 - mm.yyyy (we'll not be using)
- 1 - mm
- 2 - yyyy

After capturing those groups and storing them into indexes starting from 0, we will replace their orders, so instead of `"mm(1).yyyy(2)"` they are replaced by `"yyyy(2).mm(1)"`.